# Centralised audio unit with Redux?

Tags: javascript, audio, reactjs, redux, flux

I'm not sure what direction is best to go when creating a centralised audio object for a sound application that has different points of interaction around the app via multiple players.

From what I can think there are a few options: Instantiate and manipulate the audio object (play, pause, load etc) and the players state (whether a track is playing, paused, buffering etc) in a player reducer. Instantiate and manipulate the audio and player state in the player actions. Or have the audio object to sit outside of the redux flow (in a lib folder for example), and interact with it directly using methods on the component in parallel with dispatching events to keep the player state inline with the audio.

Here's an example of audio in the store (not redux) - https://github.com/gillesdemey/Cumulus/blob/master/app/js/stores/currentTrackStore.js

And here it is as a separate module, running along side actions that change the player state - https://github.com/jhabdas/lumpen-radio/blob/master/src/lib/audio.es6

Does anyone have any thoughts in terms of best practices, or any suggestions how to approach it.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Definitely do *not* manipulate the audio object itself inside of a reducer.  Reducers are supposed to be pure, and solely concerned about applying updates to state.

Beyond that, the two typical places to put something persistent like that would either be in a middleware, or in a UI component.  The [Middleware](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/middleware.md) page of my Redux addons catalog shows numerous examples of putting some stateful external object into a middleware.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's what I understand about reducers, which is why I didn't go down that route. Middleware works for me right now - just not sure where the best place to add event listeners to the audio (progress etc). On a side note - what's your take on keeping something like elapsed time in the store - e.g. dispatching the current time of the audio one every time update. This way the time can be centralised and accessed with ease. or is that way too performance heavy?